# Back-End (JVM) internal error. Why do i get this IDE error but others with the same code do not?

Tags: kotlin, illegalstateexception

I'm part of a group that is developing a program in Kotlin. I have recently pulled fresh code off the development branch. The problem is i get this strange error. I am the only person that gets it; my groupmates have the same code and it runs fine for them.

I've tried googling for the error. I didn't find any help as it is quite a specific one. Plus like i said my groupmates do not get this error. It is therefore probably not related to the code.

The error i get is this:

```
Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
Cause: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Error type encountered: [ERROR : For SuccessOrFailure] (ErrorType).
Cause: Error type encountered: [ERROR : For SuccessOrFailure] (ErrorType).
File being compiled at position: (32,28) in C:/Users/Gebruiker/Desktop/Repo/game/src/main/kotlin/nl/han/asd/a1/network/networkstates/EndRoundState.kt
The root cause was thrown at: KotlinTypeMapper.java:116
File being compiled at position: file://C:/Users/Gebruiker/Desktop/Repo/game/src/main/kotlin/nl/han/asd/a1/network/networkstates/EndRoundState.kt
The root cause was thrown at: ExpressionCodegen.java:322
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationErrorHandler.lambda$static$0(CompilationErrorHandler.java:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.doGenerateFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:446)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:142)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:402)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:937)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:977)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:936)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:400)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Error type encountered: [ERROR : For SuccessOrFailure] (ErrorType).
Cause: Error type encountered: [ERROR : For SuccessOrFailure] (ErrorType).
File being compiled at position: (32,28) in C:/Users/Gebruiker/Desktop/Repo/game/src/main/kotlin/nl/han/asd/a1/network/networkstates/EndRoundState.kt
The root cause was thrown at: KotlinTypeMapper.java:116
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:322)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:281)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallGenerator$DefaultCallGenerator.genValueAndPut(CallGenerator.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallBasedArgumentGenerator.generateExpression(CallBasedArgumentGenerator.java:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ArgumentGenerator.generate(ArgumentGenerator.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2461)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2433)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValueWithLeaveTask.putSelector(StackValue.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putStackValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:378)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:363)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:358)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generateInitializers(MemberCodegen.java:493)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ConstructorCodegen.generatePrimaryConstructorImpl(ConstructorCodegen.java:213)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ConstructorCodegen.access$000(ConstructorCodegen.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ConstructorCodegen$1.doGenerateBody(ConstructorCodegen.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:674)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:435)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:266)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ConstructorCodegen.generatePrimaryConstructor(ConstructorCodegen.java:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ImplementationBodyCodegen.generateConstructors(ImplementationBodyCodegen.java:462)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateBody(ClassBodyCodegen.java:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassOrObject(PackageCodegenImpl.java:161)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassesAndObjectsInFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:66)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error type encountered: [ERROR : For SuccessOrFailure] (ErrorType).
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper$1.processErrorType(KotlinTypeMapper.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.kotlin.TypeSignatureMappingKt.mapType(typeSignatureMapping.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.mapType(KotlinTypeMapper.java:512)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.writeParameterType(KotlinTypeMapper.java:1518)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.writeParameter(KotlinTypeMapper.java:1488)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.writeParameter(KotlinTypeMapper.java:1477)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.lambda$mapSignatureWithCustomParameters$4(KotlinTypeMapper.java:1295)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4745)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4753)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.mapSignatureWithCustomParameters(KotlinTypeMapper.java:1293)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.mapSignature(KotlinTypeMapper.java:1212)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.KotlinTypeMapper.mapSignatureWithGeneric(KotlinTypeMapper.java:1171)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy.mapMethodSignature(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:204)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:183)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.coroutines.CoroutineCodegenForLambda.generateResumeImpl(CoroutineCodegen.kt:421)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.coroutines.CoroutineCodegenForLambda.generateClosureBody(CoroutineCodegen.kt:234)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClosureCodegen.generateBody(ClosureCodegen.java:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.coroutines.CoroutineCodegenForLambda.generateBody(CoroutineCodegen.kt:242)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genClosure(ExpressionCodegen.java:1022)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genClosure(ExpressionCodegen.java:992)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitLambdaExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:983)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.visitLambdaExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtLambdaExpression.accept(KtLambdaExpression.java:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.genQualified(ExpressionCodegen.java:299)
    ... 70 more
```

I'm sure this has to do with my IDE or some local setting. Again, my groupmates don't get this error. The file that is mentioned in the error, EndRoundState.kt, however looks like this. If this helps clarify my problem.

```
package nl.han.asd.a1.network.networkstates

import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import nl.han.asd.a1.network.NetworkLogic
import nl.han.asd.a1.network.Player
import nl.han.asd.a1.network.networkmessages.NetworkMessage
import nl.han.asd.a1.network.networkmessages.NetworkMessageTypes.*
import nl.han.asd.a1.network.networkmessages.messagetypes.GameData
import nl.han.asd.a1.utilities.gameclock.IClock

class EndRoundState(networkLogic: NetworkLogic, var players: MutableList<Player>, hash: String, val clock: IClock) : NetworkState(networkLogic) {

    private var rightstate = true
    private val endRoundDuration = 5000 //How long should the program be in this state? default = 5000
    private val checkTimerInterval = 500L //How often should we check if the timer has expired. default = 500L

    init {
        var hashes: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        players.forEach {
            if (it.hash != null) {
                hashes.add(it.hash.toString())
            }
        }
        val rightHash = getRightHash(hashes)
        if (hash == rightHash) {
            this.networkLogic.correctGameState(hash)
        } else {
            rightstate = false
        }
        GlobalScope.launch {
            //launch a coroutine that will run alongside the other code. Think of it as a thread-lite. This will change the state after endRoundDuration expires
            val endTime: Long = clock.getCurrentTime() + endRoundDuration
            while (true) {
                delay(checkTimerInterval)
                if (clock.getCurrentTime() >= endTime) {
                    networkLogic.startNewRound()
                    return@launch
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun handleMessage(message: NetworkMessage, ip: String) {
        when (message.networkMessageType) {
            ROUND_IS_OVER -> ignore()
            CONNECT_REQUEST -> ignore()
            CONNECT_RESPONSE -> ignore()
            GAME_ANNOUNCE -> ignore()
            GAME_DATA -> {
                if (!rightstate) {
                    val gameData = message as GameData
                    this.networkLogic.setGameState(gameData.data.game)
                }
            }
            INITIATOR_MESSAGE -> ignore()
            MOVE -> TODO()
            RECONNECT_REQUEST -> TODO()
        }
    }

    private fun ignore() {

    }

    private fun getRightHash(hashes: MutableList<String>): String {
        val frequenciesByHash = hashes.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
        var highestCount = 0
        var rightHash: String? = null
        frequenciesByHash.forEach {
            if (it.value > highestCount) {
                highestCount = it.value
                rightHash = it.key
            }
        }

        return run {if(rightHash.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else rightHash!!}
    }
}
```

I just want the code to compile on my machine, like it does for my collegues. It does compile through Maven, just not through IntelliJ.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using incremental compilation? Can you try deleting everything that was built (read: `target/`, `build/`, `out/`, etc., depending on what you are using) and rebuilding?

Comment: Yes, i have done this. Both manually and with mvn clean install (Maven)

Comment: Could you specify your OS version, JDK version, kotlin version, how you build your code? Do you get this error during compilation through IDE? Or via maven too? Did you compare your local environment with your colleagues' ones?

Comment: Using windows 7, Java 8, Kotlin 1.3.11. Maven does compile, i forgot to mention that. I am using IntelliJ Ultimate.

Comment: I also invalidated caches and restarted IntelliJ. No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by uninstalling IntelliJ including all settings/plugins and reinstalling.
Uninstalling the IDE without removing settings/plugins did not work.

Comment: Reinstalling IntellijIDEA solved the issue for me, too

Answer (score 3):

I fixed by just upgrading kotlin plugin. My plugin version currently is 1.3.41-release-IJ2018.2-1

Comment: I fixed it too, with upgrading 1.4.32 to 1.5.21

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this in one of our test-cases where we had a function with a long name.
Granted this development machine was a Windows 10 machine, and Windows has a history of having problems with long filenames, https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2006950-file-path-too-long-shortening-names-is-only-the-solution.

Try to see if the filename or the function names is too long and shorten it.
It certainly helped me to reduce the 93 character test function name to 70 characters.

Also check to see if you are using weird characters and emojis, some times they can mess up the file generation.

Have fun and be safe out there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by using my custom `suspend operator fun plusAssign` and calling it by `+=`. When I **replace the `+=` by explicit `plusAssign`**, it compiles fine. I can also use the same `+=` elsewhere just fine. No idea what's going on.